# Haxe / OpenFL / Flixel

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I've been looking through the sites of Haxe / OpenFL / Flixel but am struggling to understand what each one is for.

As I understand it:

Haxe is a language that can be deployed to multiple platforms.
OpenFL is something to do with Flash.
Flixel is a library to help you make games.

Could anyone correct me/make it clearer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Haxe

To quote from [haxe.org](https://haxe.org/):

> Haxe is an open source toolkit based on a modern, high level, strictly typed programming language, a cross-compiler, a complete cross-platform standard library and ways to access each platform's native capabilities.

**Language:**

Haxe is a programming language. It's similar to AS3, C# etc.  It is strictly typed, but has great [type inference](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-inference.html). It has a lot of powerful features such as [Pattern Matching](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-introduction.html), [Enums (ADTs)](https://haxe.org/manual/types-enum-instance.html), [Macros](https://haxe.org/manual/macro.html) etc. These work no matter which target you compile to.

**Standard Library:**

- Haxe can compile to JavaScript, C++, Flash, Java, C#, PHP, [Neko](https://nekovm.org/), [HashLink](https://hashlink.haxe.org/), Python and Lua. It has low level standard classes that work consistently across platforms, such as: [`String`](http://api.haxe.org/String.html), [`Int`](http://api.haxe.org/Int.html), [`Float`](http://api.haxe.org/Float.html), [`Date`](http://api.haxe.org/Date.html), [`Map`](http://api.haxe.org/Map.html) etc.  It also has some useful cross platform code for things like [Serialization](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/Serializer.html), [`Xml`](http://api.haxe.org/Xml.html), [`Json`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/Json.html), [`Date` formatting](http://api.haxe.org/DateTools.html) etc.
- As a general rule, anything on [api.haxe.org](https://api.haxe.org/) that is in the top level, or in the `haxe` package, is going to work whichever target you compile to.
- Each target has its own package. These let you access native capabilities of that target via [externs](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-externs.html). Eg. `js.html` has DOM externs, `flash` has externs for the Flash API, etc.
- There is the `sys` package, which is available on "backend" targets: C++, Java, Neko, HashLink, PHP, Python and Lua. It's also available on JavaScript/Node with the [hxnodejs](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxnodejs) library.

**Other stuff:**

The Haxe compiler is super fast compared to a bunch of other compilers.  That's a selling point in itself.  There's also [macros](https://haxe.org/manual/macro.html), which let you do a bunch of pre-processing in a really powerful way.  Then there's tools like Haxelib which let you link in with 3rd party libraries.

### OpenFL

When Haxe first started, Flash was still a big target, it was installed everywhere, and it was great for making games.  A lot of Flash developers liked Haxe because it was fast, type safe, open source, and gave them more features.  But the flash API (sprites, graphics, movie clips, events) only worked on Flash, not on mobile, or on HTML5 etc.  Which was a problem once flash started becoming less popular.

What OpenFL does is make that Flash API work on other Haxe targets.  So you wrote a Haxe game targeting the flash API using sprites and graphics and flash-style code.  Then, you want to compile to C++ (for targeting mobile etc).  OpenFL lets your Haxe code use the Flash API, even if targeting C++ or JavaScript.  For example, OpenFL creates the `flash.graphics.DisplayObject` class not only for flash, but for C++ and JavaScript.  So if you know how to write Flash games, you are close to writing OpenFL games already.

OpenFL also has some great tools for making it easier to deploy your games to specific platforms.  Where Haxe targets are things like "JS", "SWF", "C++", OpenFL platforms are things like "iOS", "Android", "Switch", "HTML5", "Windows EXE" etc.  When you hear about Haxe targeting mobile, a lot of the time it is OpenFL, because it works with Haxe to compile your code (into C++, JS, SWF or whatever) and then packages those binaries for mobile.

### Flixel

Haxe is a language, compiler and standard library.
OpenFL builds on this and adds the Flash API working across targets.
HaxeFlixel builds on this even further and provides game specific APIs that work on OpenFL.

An example of how it all works together:

- You create a game.  All of it is written in Haxe.  Things like player name, scores, and completion info all use data structures from the standard library.  They'll work in your game, but you could also make them work on your PHP website.
- Your game uses OpenFL to compile to Flash, HTML5, iOS and Android.  As part of OpenFL, you also have access to standard Flash API classes, like the Stage and Buttons and MouseEvents, which you might use for your menu screen.  Because OpenFL provides the flash.* classes for other targets, your app compiles to all different things.
- For your actual game, performance is important, and the flash DisplayList approach is a bit slow and not optimised for gaming. HaxeFlixel is optimised for gaming, and is very fast.  So you design your game with HaxeFlixel using their APIs.

### Summary

Haxe is a language, compiler, toolkit and standard library.  It provides the most basic tools for cross-platform code.

OpenFL is built on Haxe, and provides the Flash API to multiple targets (Flash, C++, JavaScript) and makes it easy to compile to a bunch of platforms: web, native, iOS, Android, Nintendo Switch etc.

HaxeFlixel is built on OpenFL - it uses the APIs provided by OpenFL to create a game specific framework that is high performance and easy to make 2D games.

Comment: Actually, this answer doesn't distinguish Flixel with Haxeflixel which are different. http://flixel.org/ vs https://haxeflixel.com/

Answer (score 16):

I just recently discovered HaxeFlixel, and I LOVE it! I came from making games in AS3 using Flixel, and now I'll probably never go back!

---

So, to attempt to answer your question (and the way I understand it):

Haxe is sort of the bottom layer. It's the programing language that can be compiled into Flash, Windows, Android, iOS, etc, etc, etc.

OpenFL is a software development kit which uses Haxe to make it easier and smoother to get games to work via Haxe and allow you to easily harness the power of Haxe's compatibility while not having to deal with a lot of the hassle and problems that you can get into. It takes care of a lot of the basic stuff for you and makes it easier to code.

HaxeFlixel is a 2D Game framework based on a combination of Adam Atomic's Flixel for AS3 and Flixel Power Tools by Photon Storm. It makes it easier to make 2D games in almost the same type of code as in AS3/Flixel.

When just starting out, you should only need to worry about the highest level, which in your case is HaxeFlixel.

So, to summarize a bit: Haxe is a powerful programing language. You can try to figure out how to code with it 'as-is', which is complicated, or you can use one of a number of libraries to make it easier - OpenFL is one of these libraries.

You can use OpenFL on its own, and code a game with it, or you can use one of a number of different frameworks to make it easier - HaxeFlixel is one of these frameworks. There's also the [Starling](https://github.com/openfl/starling) and [HaxePunk](https://haxepunk.com/) frameworks which have their own pros and cons.

#### Opinion Time!

I highly recommend sticking with HaxeFlixel - since it was so similar to Flixel, I managed to pick it up and learn how to use it, and made [this complete game](https://www.tims-world.com/projects/paddle-battles/) in exactly 1 month and released a Flash, Windows, and Android version all on the same day - which is outstanding considering I had not touched Haxe before, and had never had time to even start looking at Android Development before. That game's source code, by the way, is completely open source, so feel free to dig in and see how I did stuff.

The community for HaxeFlixel is also pretty amazing and people will help you out and answer questions.

It's really not too hard to jump in and start working with HaxeFlixel:

http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/getting-started/

Follow those steps and you'll at least have a `Hello, World!` up and running in minutes (excluding the time it takes to download and install all the stuff). Like I mentioned earlier, until you're more comfortable with it, just follow the directions for Haxe and OpenFL but don't even think about it for now!

Good luck! And let me know if you make it anywhere or not!

Comment: My antivirus (Malware Bytes) blocked your game from running and scanned it first. It came out safe, but that initial safety check was annoying. Other `exe` files run normally on my computer. Any way to make HaxeFlixel exe games run without this for end users?

Comment: @Prid I think the problem here is that all antivirus programs by default see new programs (or rarely run ones) as potential malware until they confirm them to be safe. I believe the only way around it is to make your `.exe` popular (have a lot of users using it) so its fingerprint is already in the various antivirus' databases. There is also digital signing of software, which might help, but I don't really know :)